# Automatically install a new package in R

Tags: r, package

I have wrote a function for the packages which I have already installed.
Within that I just want to write a statement where a new package needs to be installed automatically, once we call it. I want to install ROCR package using this function below.

```
libraries <- function()

list.of.packages <- c("caTools", "caret", "glmnet","rpart","rpart.plot","randomForest","rattle",
                   "e1071")
new.packs<- if(list.of.packages[!list.of.packages %in% installed.packages() [,"Package"])]{
install.packages("new.packs")
library(new.packs)
}else {
print("All packages installed")
```

}
}

Comment: Did you search CRAN? There are a few packages that provide this functionality (i.e. enable automatic installation of packages  if they don't exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this general approach:

```
if(!"caret" %in% installed.packages()) install.packages("caret")
```

Can be adjusted to your needs, as in getting vector of not yet installed packages and then passing it to `install.packages`:

```
list.of.packages <- c("caTools", "caret", "glmnet","rpart","rpart.plot","randomForest","rattle",
                      "e1071")

if(length(which(!list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()))){
  install.packages(list.of.packages[!list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()])
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have just tried the code if worked. However, can just tell me, how to call the package which has been installed, inside that function.Sorry for asking too many questions.

IN R, we call the installed package as library(caret)

Comment: It's not a function, it's merely an "if statement". Why wouldn't you just add a loop to it, like `for(i in list.of.packages) library(i, character.only = T)` ?

Answer (score 3):

library pacman does this for you.

e.g.

```
pacman::p_load(data.table, lubridate)
```

loads the libraries and installs them if they are not available.

Comment: I'm totally unbiased when I say that this is the best package for the task.  No bias here. None.